# Prevent CMS identification

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, drupal, content-management-system, prestashop

I have a little curiosity. I often use extensions like Wappalyzer to try to understand certain sites about which CMS are based and, in this regard, I would have a question: is there a way to prevent extensions similar to the one mentioned above from identifying the CMS used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try, but I don't think that you can successfully hide CMS behind your site and that attempt is waste of time. For drupal check on this page:

https://www.drupal.org/node/766404

Comment: I will try, just to see the result!

Comment: Just make backup before you start working on that because it may happen that you site stops working...

Answer (score 0):

Most CMS can be run as headless CMS, decoupling backend and frontend. They either render a static set of html pages, or a JSON file with all the sites data, which is then rendered by some kind of Javascript app. This way no one can figure out where the data is coming from, or if there was a CMS involved at all.